# i have records to be processed in vCommonRecords. i am not receiving the emails with expected results

Tags: apex, email-template, dynamic-soql, singleemailmessage

My actual task is :
1.I have Account object it is having 2 child objects contacts and Orders.
2. need to process the account records with record type = Branch Integrated
3. need to send email receipents to contats having flag value = true.
4.oder is having child object ojectrderlineitem .
5. need to send orderline object info in the template.
6. order line items records have 2 common fields ASN_Ship_To_Id__c,ASN_KN_SID__c.
7.i need to process same ASN_Ship_To_Id__c,ASN_KN_SID__c records info into single email template.
i have written the below logic the logic getting the list of orderline items correctly in vCommonRecords .
but while sending the emails i am not getting the results correctly. 
global class OrderLineItemUtilBatch implements Database.Batchable{
    global string reportContent;
    global string vQuery;
    global OrderLineItemUtilBatch()
    {
        reportContent = '';
        vQuery = 'SELECT ASN_Carrier_Name__c,ASN_Ship_To_Id__c,ASN_ETA__c,ASN_Fax__c,ASN_KN_SID__c,ASN_Notification_Alert__c,ASN_Phone__c,ASN_PO_Number__c,ASN_Sales_Order_Line_Number__c,ASN_Ship_From_Address_1__c,ASN_Ship_From_Address_2__c,ASN_Ship_From_Country__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_City__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_Postal_Code__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_State__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_1__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_2__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_3__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_4__c,ASN_Ship_to_Location__c,ASN_Top_Line_Model__c,Id,Line_Description__c,Name,Order_Line__c,Order_Ship_Date__c,Quantity__c,Scheduled_Date__c,Ship_From__c,Ship_To_Address__c,Ship_To_City__c,Ship_To_Country__c,Ship_To_State_Province__c,Ship_To_Zipcode__c,Star__c ,order__r.OrderNumber,Serial_Number__c,order__r.account.Recordtypeid FROM Order_Line_Item__c where Serial_Number__c !=null and order__r.account.Recordtype.Name  = \'Branch Integrated\'';

```
}
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    System.debug('##Entry QueryLocator');
     //string vQuery = 'SELECT ASN_Carrier_Name__c,ASN_Ship_To_Id__c,ASN_ETA__c,ASN_Fax__c,ASN_KN_SID__c,ASN_Notification_Alert__c,ASN_Phone__c,ASN_PO_Number__c,ASN_Sales_Order_Line_Number__c,ASN_Ship_From_Address_1__c,ASN_Ship_From_Address_2__c,ASN_Ship_From_Country__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_City__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_Postal_Code__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location_State__c,ASN_Ship_From_Location__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_1__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_2__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_3__c,ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_4__c,ASN_Ship_to_Location__c,ASN_Top_Line_Model__c,Id,Line_Description__c,Name,Order_Line__c,Order_Ship_Date__c,Quantity__c,Scheduled_Date__c,Ship_From__c,Ship_To_Address__c,Ship_To_City__c,Ship_To_Country__c,Ship_To_State_Province__c,Ship_To_Zipcode__c,Star__c ,order__r.OrderNumber,Serial_Number__c,order__r.account.Recordtypeid FROM Order_Line_Item__c where Serial_Number__c !=null and order__r.account.Recordtype.Name  = \'Branch Integrated\'';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(vQuery);

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Order_Line_Item__c> vLstOL)
{

    System.debug('##Entry execute');
   Map<String, LIST<Order_Line_Item__c>> vMapOLI = new Map<String, LIST<Order_Line_Item__c>>();
   if(vMapOLI != NULL)
           {
               for(order_Line_Item__c tempOLI : vLstOL)
                 {
                      if(vMapOLI.get(tempOLI.ASN_KN_SID__c + tempOLI.ASN_Ship_To_Id__c) != NUll)
                       {
                            List<order_Line_Item__c> oldList = vMapOLI.get(tempOLI.ASN_KN_SID__c + tempOLI.ASN_Ship_To_Id__c);
                            oldList.add(tempOLI);
                       }
                      else
                       {
                           LIST<order_Line_Item__c> newList = new LIST<order_Line_Item__c>();
                           newList.add(tempOLI);
                           vMapOLI.put(tempOLI.ASN_KN_SID__c + tempOLI.ASN_Ship_To_Id__c , newList);

                       }
                  }
            }
                 system.debug('vMapOLI '+vMapOLI.keyset());
                 system.debug('vMapOLI '+vMapOLI.keyset());
                 list<order_Line_Item__c> vCommonRecords = new list<order_Line_Item__c>();
      for(string str1 : vMapOLI.keyset())

       {  
          vCommonRecords = vMapOLI.get(str1);
          system.debug('vCommonRecords '+vCommonRecords );

       }
       Set<Id> vSetAccId = new Set<Id>();
       for(order_Line_Item__c vOL: vLstOL)
           {
             vSetAccId.add(vOL.order__r.account.id);
           }       
    List<Account> vLstAccount = [SELECT Id,Name,(Select Id, LastName,ASN_Notification_Alert__c from Contacts where ASN_Notification_Alert__c = true ) FROM Account where Id In:vSetAccId];
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> vLstEmail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage vSEmail;

    for(Account vAccount: vLstAccount)
        {
          for(order_Line_Item__c str : vCommonRecords)
             {
            reportContent='';
```

reportContent += '';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='

#### Shipment Notification

';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='Ship From :  ';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Location__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Address_1__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Address_2__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Location_City__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Location_State__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Country__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_From_Location_Postal_Code__c+'';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='Ship To:  '+str.ASN_Ship_to_Location__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_1__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_2__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_3__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_4__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Ship_To_City__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Ship_To_State_Province__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Ship_To_Country__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Ship_To_Zipcode__c+'';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='**Shipment Details:** ';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='**SID:**  '+str.ASN_KN_SID__c+'  &nbsp';
reportContent +='**Carrier:**  '+str.ASN_Carrier_Name__c+' &nbsp';
reportContent +='**Ship Date:**  '+str.Order_Ship_Date__c+' &nbsp';
reportContent +='**ETA:**  '+string.valueof(str.ASN_ETA__c)+'  
';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='**Shipped Quantity**';
reportContent +='**PO Number**';
reportContent +='**Sales Order**';
reportContent +='**Line**';
reportContent +='**Item Number**';
reportContent +='**Serial Number**';
reportContent +='**Description**';
reportContent +=''+str.Quantity__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_PO_Number__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Order__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Sales_Order_Line_Number__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.ASN_Top_Line_Model__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Serial_Number__c+'';
reportContent +=''+str.Line_Description__c+'';
reportContent +='
';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='**Terex Sales Contact:** ';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='If you have any questions about your order, please contact your Sales Representative or';
reportContent +='Customer Service at:';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='Customer Service Phone:'+str.ASN_Phone__c+'';
reportContent +='Customer Service Fax:'+str.ASN_Fax__c+'';
reportContent +='
';
reportContent +='**Shipment Tracking:** ';
reportContent +='';
reportContent +='**.** Live shipment tracking is available through our integrated logistics portal at: http://google.com
';
reportContent +='           **.**Please note that the ETA is a target and does not guarantee delivery on this date – please check the portal for the latest
'; 
reportContent +='             updates
';
reportContent +='**.**If you want to sign up for the portal, have username/password issues, or any questions about your shipment, please contact Customer Service
';
reportContent +='**.**Please also note that:
';
reportContent +='           **.** Tracking will not be available for any international ExWorks or FCA shipments after shipment notification
';
reportContent +='           **.**Product descriptions may differ from the bill of lading for letter of credit shipments
';
reportContent +='THANK YOU FOR YOUR ORDER ';
reportContent +='';

```
                if(str.order__r.account.id == vAccount.Id)
                {
                  for(Contact vContact: vAccount.Contacts)
                  {
                    vSEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    vSEmail.setTargetObjectId(vContact.Id);
                    vSEmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    vSEmail.setHtmlBody(reportContent);
                    vSEmail.setWhatId(str.Id); 
                    vLstEmail.add(vSEmail);
                  }
                }

              }
            }

            if(!vLstEmail.isEmpty())
            {
              Messaging.sendEmail(vLstEmail);
            }

}


global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
```

}

Comment: Right now, it is very hard to tell what you are asking. Please *edit your question* (not in comments) to include a full sentence that ends with a question mark and makes clear what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're after, but I think you want to group together Order Line records based on a composite key of `ASN_Ship_To_Id__c + ASN_KN_SID__c`

The following is a simple version that might work. I haven't had a chance to test it, so feel free to update if the syntax isn't quite right.

```
Map<String, List<Order_Line_Item__c>> orderLinesToEmail = new Map<String, List<Order_Line_Item__c>>();
List<Order_Line_Item__c> orderLines = [SELECT ASN_Ship_To_Id__c, ASN_ETA__c, ASN_Fax__c, ASN_KN_SID__c, ASN_Notification_Alert__c, ASN_Phone__c, ASN_PO_Number__c, ASN_Sales_Order_Line_Number__c, ASN_Ship_From_Address_1__c, ASN_Ship_From_Address_2__c, ASN_Ship_From_Country__c, ASN_Ship_From_Location_City__c, ASN_Ship_From_Location_Postal_Code__c, ASN_Ship_From_Location_State__c, ASN_Ship_From_Location__c, ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_1__c, ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_2__c, ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_3__c, ASN_Ship_To_Location_Address_4__c, ASN_Ship_to_Location__c, ASN_Top_Line_Model__c, Id, Line_Description__c, Name, Order_Line__c, Order_Ship_Date__c, Quantity__c, Scheduled_Date__c, Ship_From__c, Ship_To_Address__c, Ship_To_City__c, Ship_To_Country__c, Ship_To_State_Province__c, Ship_To_Zipcode__c, Star__c, order__r.OrderNumber, Serial_Number__c, order__r.account.Recordtypeid FROM Order_Line_Item__c where Serial_Number__c != null and order__r.account.Recordtype.Name = 'Branch Integrated'];

for(Order_Line_Item__c orderLine : orderLines)
{
    String key = orderLine.ASN_Ship_To_Id__c + orderLine.ASN_KN_SID__c;

    // check if we already have the orderline in the map
    if(!orderLinesToEmail.containsKey(key)) 
    {
        orderLinesToEmail.put(key, new List<Order_Line_Item__c>());
    }

    // add in the current order line to the List
    orderLinesToEmail.get(key).add(orderLine);
}
```

It's not clear what you want to do with the results though.  You could loop through the map and create a SingleEmailMessage that would include information from all related order lines.

If this solves your issue, please mark it accordingly, and if it doesn't, please provide more information.

BTW, please please please don't put spaces around the < and > when declaring your List/Map/Set variables.  It makes it so hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for your help i got the exact results. And i want to know one more thing is it possible to process multiple records in a single email template. If it so could you tell me the approach.

Comment: could you please help me in sending emails through below code . i am not receiving the expected results.

Comment: you really should leave the original question as it is and post a new question on how to send emails.  Now this answer doesn't make any sense, so it's not going to help anyone else that stumbles upon it.  Can you change the question back to what it was, and post a new question?